# Reverse order of radar graph in R?

Tags: r, radar-chart

I'm using the `radarchart()` function in the `fmsb` library of R. My dataframe has ordered categories as column names: A, B, C, D, E, F, G and H.  The function plots them in counter-clockwise order.  I want them to be in clockwise order. How can I do this?

[image: Current]

This is an image of what it's currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can just reorder the columns in the data.frame to get what you want.  The simplest thing to do is use `rev(MyData)`, but then the chart will not start with the first column at 12 O'clock. So below I use a different reordering.

```
library(fmsb)

## Create some bogus data
MyData = matrix(abs(rnorm(40)), nrow=5, ncol=8)
MyData = data.frame(t(apply(MyData, 1, sort)))
colnames(MyData) = LETTERS[1:8]

## Compare the two radarcharts
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
radarchart(MyData, maxmin=FALSE, title="Counter-Clockwise")
radarchart(MyData[,c(1, 8:2)], maxmin=FALSE, title="Clockwise")
```

[image: RadarCharts]